# How to insert value in word FormField as string from sql

Tags: sql, vba, ms-word

I've got a VBA script, but I get error "Compile error: Object required"

I added the following references in word VBA for application, but it didn't help

```
-Visual Basic For Applications
-Microsoft Word 12.0 Object library
-OLE Automation
-Microsoft office 12.0 Object Library
-Microsoft ActiveX data Objects 2.8 Library
-Microsoft ActiveX data Objects Recordset 2.8 Library
-Microsoft remote Data Services 2.7 Library
```

What's missing in this script?

===========================

```
Sub ftbox()
Dim spinr As String
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection

Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
    cnn.Open "lv", "xx", "xxxxxx"

Set spinr = cnn.Execute("select spinnr from cust where custid=" & ActiveDocument.FormField("custid").Result)

ActiveDocument.FormFields("reg").Result = spinr

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are receiving the error because:

```
Set spinr = cnn.Execute("select spinnr from cust where custid=" & ActiveDocument.FormField("custid").Result)
```

should be:

```
Set spinr = cnn.Execute("select spinnr from cust where custid=" & ActiveDocument.FormFields("custid").Result)
```

That being said, there looks like lots of weirdness going on in your code.  This:

```
cnn.Open "lv", "xx", "xxxxxx"
```

looks very strange to me.  I'm not sure what data source you are trying to connect to (unless you just did it for posting).  Also:

```
Dim spinr As String

...

Set spinr = cnn.Execute("select spinnr from cust where custid=" & ActiveDocument.FormField("custid").Result)
```

The object returned by cnn.Execute is an ADODB.Recordset, not a string.  spinr should be an ADODB.Recordset type.

Finally:

```
ActiveDocument.FormFields("reg").Result = spinr
```

should be more like:

```
ActiveDocument.FormFields("reg").Result = spinr.Fields("spinnr")
```

because spinnr will be an Recordset object.  You don't close your connection or deallocate your objects.  May cause issues if you try to connect to your datasource, especially if the code breaks and you End the procedure. I don't know the Word objects that well, so you you may have even more issues.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use your code and got the same error. I think that the error is occurring because you are pre-fixing a string (assignment) with SET. If you remove the SET then you get a different error.

As already mentioned, you need to use a recordset:

```
Dim rst as ADODB.Recordset
```

Then run the following 2 lines after you have opened the connection:

```
Set rst = cnn.Execute("select spinnr from cust where custid=" & ActiveDocument.FormFields("custid").Result)
spinr = rst.GetString(adClipString, -1, vbTab)
```

I hope this helps.